# How to add a badge above a button?

Tags: java, android, material-design

In my MainActivity class, I have this button:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/target"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/speak"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
    android:text="@string/target" />
```

I now want to add a badge with the number 1, using Material Design (see the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/badging)).

This is how I tried:

```java
public void setBadge() {
    BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable =  BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
    badgeDrawable.setNumber(1);
    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, findViewById(R.id.target));
}
```

but what I get is the error

> 'attachBadgeDrawable(com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable, android.view.View, android.widget.FrameLayout)' in 'com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeUtils' cannot be applied to '(com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable, android.view.View)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried this on a device with <18 API this might work;

In your XML wrap the button with a `FrameLayout`;

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="HELLO"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In your Activity;

```
//I've used post to eliminate race condition between the button and its badge.
button.post(() -> {
    BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable =  BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
    badgeDrawable.setNumber(1);
    //Note that there is a third argument which is our FrameLayout
    BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, findViewById(R.id.button), findViewById(R.id.frame));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the error _Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getDrawingRect(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference_

Comment: Be careful about the anchor view you are passing here. (For example don't pass R.id.button instead of R.id.target) It seems like it is null.  BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, findViewById(R.id.button), findViewById(R.id.frame));

Comment: Oh sure, that was my mistake. It works fine. Thank you!